# Concatenate CSS selectors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Is there a smarter way where I can use `$self` instead of using `foo` in `$('.foo.bar')`... ? It feels like the extra foo is redundent. I don't want to look through some selector I already found.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
    $self = $(this);
    $('.foo.bar').removeClass('bar'); // Works but feels wrong.
    //$self('bar').removeClass('bar'); // Use something that doesn't uses 'foo' again..
});
```

**EDIT**:

Markup code:

```
<div class="foo bar">
</div>
```

Notice `$('.foo.bar')` doesn't have a whitespace between `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to remove the css `.bar` class only from the clicked elements or from all of the `.foo` elements?

Comment: I think your selector is correct

Comment: Hmm can't get any of the sugestions to work, I most have a bug somewhere. I will try more

Comment: @radbyx: If you're having problems getting any of the suggestions to work, can you post a jsFiddle/ jsBin to demonstrate what you have?

Comment: Yes I will build a fiddle after trying your answer. Last one i havn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the current answers assume that the `.foo` clicked on will be the *only* `.foo` with the class `bar`.

... if that is always the case, then great, but note that these answers *aren't* direct substitutions for what you've got (since you look for *all* `.foo`'s with the class `bar`). The following *would* be a *more* direct substitution:

```
var foos = $('.foo').on('click', function () {
    $self = $(this);

    foos.filter('.bar').removeClass('bar');
});
```

... but note that this code *still* **isn't** a direct substitution, since your code will get the `.foo`'s *in the DOM at the time the click event was fired*, whereas the alternative I propose will get the `.foo`'s *at the time the click event was bound*.

---

Also, checking whether a jQuery element has a class, before removing that class, is kind of redundant; as jQuery won't barf if you tell it to remove a non-existant class from an element; it just won't do anything.

```
if (self.hasClass('bar')) {
    self.removeClass('bar');
}
```

... instead, just do this:

```
self.removeClass('bar');
```

Comment: Saving the foos outside works for me. What is the lifetime of the foos then? Do I have to worry about it poluting the global namespace or the window object?
I'm not adding any foo's dynamically.

Comment: @radbyx: The lifetime will be as long as any closures capturing the `foos` variable (in other words, the lifetime of any functions which has access to `foos`). In the simple case you've reduced your code to, that'll be the lifetime of the click handler on your `.foo`'s. I assume the code is within a `$(document).ready()` block, in the case `foos` is defined local to that block, and not in the global scope at all. If you wanted to reduce the scope further, you could use an IIFE, a'la http://jsfiddle.net/oq7fu1hs/

Comment: Thanks for the info. BTW your solutions works fine and make sense, but I have a last question. It's still feels like a tradeoff, not only a win. Your solution reused what you allready found, but introduce a variable. Mine is slower, I guess, but don't have a new variable. What would you use? I know in the last it's probably not even notiable, because it's a static menu with few items actually. :)

Comment: @radbyx: For what it's worth, variables in JavaScript are *really* cheap, so you'll almost never lose out using them. In the more general sense, a performance gain in one area, is usually at the expense of losing performance elsewhere; in your original code, whilst you didn't have the (admittedly tiny, but still present) "setup" cost of defining the `foos` variable, you did suffer the cost of having to re-lookup `.foo.bar` each time the click handler was invoked. In my code, you have the initial setup time, but gain in the click handler.

Comment: ... in these situations, I try and optimize for the "common case"; you incur the setup cost once, but the click handler could be fired multiple times, so in my eyes it makes sense to optimize the click handler. Because of this, I'd go with my approach of using the `foos` variable; but again, it's admittedly for *tiny* performance gains here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge my friend. It makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** `hasClass()`

```
$self.hasClass("bar") && $self.removeClass('bar');
```

**Method 2** `is()`

```
$seld.is(".bar")  && $self.removeClass('bar');
```

**Method 3** `filter()`

```
$seld.filter(".bar").removeClass('bar');
```

Comment: Method 1 and 2 won't work because `is` and `hasClass` return boolean values, not jQuery objects. Also, `filter` would find all child elements which have the class of `bar`, not just the clicked element only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `is` or `hasClass` to check to see if the current element also has the `bar` class:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
    $self = $(this);
    $self.is('.bar') && $self.removeClass('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple logic: `If X has a class Y, remove class Y from X.`

Here is the code:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {

    $self = $(this);

    if($self.hasClass('bar'))
        $self.removeClass('bar');

});
```

Readup:

- [`.hasClass()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- [`.removeClass()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id for each parent element, you can use something like :

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
   $('#'+this.id).removeClass('bar'); // it will remove child class bar
)};
```